# Check if there is a ::after in a scraped website

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website with the following html which describes a checkbox:

```html
html = 
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-block">
    <input type="checkbox" data-false-value="'0'" data-true-value="'1'" 
    id="cover42" data-change="calculateOfferThree()" data- 
    model="result.formuladb.Wrapper.cover42_protection.value">
    <label for="cover42" class="form-labels ng-binding"> 
    ::before 
    "Cover 42 protection" 
    ::after
    </label>
</div>
```

When the checkbox is checked, I get the '::after' in my html, if it is unchecked it's not there. Unfortunately that seems the only thing that changes.
Now I want to find out, if the checkbox is selected or not.
I think the easiest way is to get everything within the   and check if there is an '::after' in.

So I tried:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium

# I open the website with the html mentioned above via selenium webbrowser
page_content = driver.page_source
soup = (page_content, 'html.parser')
```

But when I have a look at the soup the '::after' and '::before' are not there...
Anyone having an idea how I can find out if the checkbox is marked or not?

Edit:
Ok the ::after/::before is already missing in the line above:

`page_content = driver.page_source`

That means the answers so far don't help (at least not with the first step)

Answer (score 0):

Just get the text within the `div` tag and check whether the text contains `::after`. Here is how you do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-block">
    <input type="checkbox" data-false-value="'0'" data-true-value="'1'" 
    id="cover42" data-change="calculateOfferThree()" data- 
    model="result.formuladb.Wrapper.cover42_protection.value">
    <label for="cover42" class="form-labels ng-binding"> 
    ::before 
    "Cover 42 protection" 
    ::after
    </label>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-block")

txt = div.text.replace(" ","").strip()

if "::after" in txt:
    print("Checked")
```

Output:

```
Checked
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have `::after` and `::before` you can perform a check like:

```
# no class selectors you can add it because this is the only div shown
myDiv = soup.find("div")
checked = False
for x in ["::after","::before"]:
  if x in myDiv.text.strip():
    checked = True
```

Get the `checked` variable